# Capitalize a sequence of lines entered via console input and print/return

Tags: python, python-2.x, recursion

I'm running through the popular python practice exercises located at github:
https://github.com/zhiwehu/Python-programming-exercises/blob/master/100%2B%20Python%20challenging%20programming%20exercises.txt

I recently discovered recursive functions. So when asked the following in the above link:

```
Question 9
Level 2

Question£º
Write a program that accepts sequence of lines as input and prints the lines after making all characters in the sentence capitalized.
Suppose the following input is supplied to the program:
Hello world
Practice makes perfect
Then, the output should be:
HELLO WORLD
PRACTICE MAKES PERFECT
```

My answer is:

```
def capitalize_line(string=""):
    """Capitalize and add a newline to the input str(if present)"""
    inp = input("enter: ").upper()
    string = "\n".join([string, inp]) if string and inp else "".join([string, inp])
    if not inp:
        print(string)
        return string
    return capitalize_line(string=string)
```

E.g. Two inputs of 'hello' and 'world' would return 'HELLO\nWORLD'.

Is this a suitable solution? Pythonic?

The link answer was:

```
Solution:
lines = []
while True:
    s = raw_input()
    if s:
        lines.append(s.upper())
    else:
        break;

for sentence in lines:
    print sentence
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Is this pythonic ?

The answer to this question is often found by doing `import this`:

> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>   Explicit is better than implicit.
>   Simple is better than complex.
>   Complex is better than complicated.
>   Flat is better than nested.
>   Sparse is better than dense.
>   Readability counts.
>   Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
>   Although practicality beats purity.
>   Errors should never pass silently.
>   Unless explicitly silenced.
>   In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
>   There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
>   Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
>   Now is better than never.
>   Although never is often better than *right* now.
>   If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
>   If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
>   Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

---

Why is this line not pythonic ? Because it is not readable enough.

> Readability counts.

```
string = "\n".join([string, inp]) if string and inp else "".join([string, inp])
```

---

Why is this line not pythonic ? Because it contains more than one instruction by line

> Sparse is better than dense.

```
string = ('\n' if string and inp else '').join([string, inp])
```

---

Why is this line not pythonic ? Still not the prettiest way of writing that.

> Beautiful is better than ugly.

```
delimiter = '\n' if string and inp else ''
string = delimiter.join([string, inp])
```

I will say later in this post why this is still ugly and how to improve this code.

---

### Is a recursive function pythonic ?

No, yes, it's complicated. First, the **call stack hell**. Every time you call a function, python has to "store" the addresses of the caller into a call stack, the depth of the call stack is 1000, which is not much. So...

1. `while` and `for` are often better than recursive in terms of readability (not always true)
2. `while` and `for` are often better than recursive in terms of performance (not always true)
3. Everything that can be done in a loop can be done recursively (with python not always true)
4. Everything that can be done recursively can be done with a while or for loop. (always true)
5. The stack is the limit. 1000 calls comes quick, for example there are more than 1000 words in this post, it wouldn't be a good idea to use recursion to parse it, it would raise a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

---

### Is my implementation of a recursive function good ?

No, because you pass the accumulator as an argument (classic beginner mistake). You think in terms of loops, even when using recursion. Let's take a look at a simple function.

```
def sum(l):                  #  No hidden mystery accumulator
    if len(l)==1:            #  The first line is usually the stop condition
        return l[0]          #  Return the last element
    return l[0] + sum(l[1:]) #  Return the first + the sum of the rest

sum(range(42))  # 861
```

Let's take a closer look at how it calculates this:

```
def sum(l):
    if len(l)==1:
        return l[0]
    return f"({l[0]}+{sum(l[1:])})"

sum(range(10))  # '(0+(1+(2+(3+(4+(5+(6+(7+(8+9)))))))))'
```

Impressive !

---

Now look at your function:

```
def capitalize_line(string=""):     # Hidden mystery accumulator
    inp = input("enter: ").upper()  # Move this outside of your function
    # This line is already debunked
    string = "\n".join([string, inp]) if string and inp else "".join([string, inp])
    if not inp:
        print(string)    # Move this outside of your function
        return string    # You don't use this but you should
    return capitalize_line(string=string) # not using return as intended 
                         # (carrying processed data down the call stack)
```

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Using `stdin` and `stdout` inside a function whose purpose is to `capitalize` letters is not a good thing. It makes the code impossible to divide because everything is linked. The `capitalize` function should capitalize and return a string and nothing else.

### How should I write it ?

You think I will give you the solution like that... I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that !

Just kidding, but promise me you will try before looking at it:

> ```
> def capitalize(l):
>     if not l:
>         return ''
>     return l[0].upper() + '\n' + capitalize(l[1:])
> ```
>
> ```
> def capitalize(l): # alternative way
>     if len(l)==1:
>         return l[0]
>     return l[0].upper() + '\n' + capitalize(l[1:])
> ```
>
> ```
> def main(): # Python 3.8 only
>     inputs = []
>     while s:=input('enter: '): inputs.append(s)
>     print(capitalize(inputs))
> ```
>
> ```
> def main():
>     inputs = []
>     while True:
>         s = input('enter: ')
>         if not s:
>             break
>         inputs.append(s)
>     print(capitalize(inputs))
> ```
>
> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     main()   # In case someone imports your module to use your functions
> ```
>
> But You want to do like the pros don't you ? Use generators
>
> ```
> def capitalize(iterable):
>     try:
>         s = next(iterable)
>     except StopIteration:
>         return ''
>     return s.upper() + '\n' + capitalize(iterable)
> ```
>
> ```
> def inputs():
>     while True:
>         s = input('enter: ')
>         if not s:
>             break
>         yield s
> ```
>
> Even better (or worse), a recursive generator:
>
> ```
> def inputs():
>      s = input('enter: ')
>      if not s: return
>      yield s
>      yield from inputs()
> ```
>
> ```
> def main():
>     print(capitalize(inputs()))
> ```

Wow, you're still there, it means you had the time to read my entire post, and since you've time on your hands, I recommend you [Socratica](https://www.youtube.com/socratica), more specifically [the video about recursion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk0zUZW-U_M&list=PLi01XoE8jYohWFPpC17Z-wWhPOSuh8Er-&index=18).

And remember, recursion isn't often the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

While [the answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/214407/98493) by [@BenoîtPilatte](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/193138/beno%C3%AEt-pilatte) is fine as long as you want to keep this a recursive solution, here is a solution using only generators.

First, [Python 2 is going to be no longer supported in less than a year](https://pythonclock.org/). If you have not yet switched to Python 3, now is the time. As a small incentive I am going to assume Python 3 in the rest of this answer.

Now, let's start by building a generator that takes the user input until an empty line is entered:

```
def user_input():
    while True:
        s = input()
        if not s:
            return
        yield s
```

That was easy, and now we are already done, because we can just use `str.upper` directly, since the output of `input` is a string, no need for a recursive function to do it for you:

```
def solution():
    for line in user_input():
        print(line.upper())
```

Alternatively we can chain generators and use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
def solution():
    for line in map(str.upper, user_input()):
        print(line)
```

As you can see this is vastly shorter and more readable, regardless of the stack size limit in Python.